# Why can't I access the public System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form1 with a binding source created by VS as

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1
```

I have changed private to public

Sill Intellisence doesn't recognize

```
form1.BindingSource
```

within another form2

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.bindingSource1 = ...;
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the name of the field - only the type. For instance, it might be:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;
```

You also need to make sure your `form1` variable is of the right type (rather than just `Form`). If you could give a short but *complete* example, that would help.

Personally I would avoid making the fields public though - if you really need to expose the binding source, use a property to access it.

Comment: You're right but I made a mistake in the question so I corrected. 

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Again, a short but *complete* example would help. The code you've got looks like it will work, if the field is genuinely public. What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, BindingSource is the type of the member.  It's not clear from your sample what the name of the member is.  So you can in effect be binding to the wrong name